# Suppress successful lint output in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Is there a switch to turn off the lint output like this:

```
:app:lint
Ran lint on variant release: 0 issues found
Ran lint on variant debug: 0 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:/.../project/app/build/outputs/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to .../project/app/build/outputs/lint-results.xml
```

It should be pretty obvious from a

```
:app:lint
:app:nextTaskAfterLint
```

output that:

1. Lint ran
2. No issues found
3. No-one wants to look at an almost empty html page saying "Congratulations!"

I tried these options:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        quiet true // no effect at all
        textOutput file('lint.x') // no output to given file, and still outputs to stdout
    }
}
```

It would be nice to have the above output if the issues found is > 0, but it's not a big problem since I can stop the build by `warningsAsErrors true` and `abortOnError true` if any issues found.

Comment: It would be worth filing a feature request at http://b.android.com

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78580

Answer (score 0):

According to doc, you can exclude a task with a command line:
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#sec%3aexcluding_tasks_from_the_command_line

So you can use this command to skip lint:

```
gradlew build -x lint
```

To avoid the log output, you can check the Lint task here:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/gradle_0.13.3/build-system/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/tasks/Lint.groovy

You can find at line 90:

```
 if (!mFatalOnly) {
         println "Ran lint on variant " + variant.getName() + ": " + warnings.size() +
                        " issues found"
  }
```

Hovewer I didn't find how to set this variable-

Here you can find all options available today with the gradle plugin 0.13.3:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/gradle_0.13.3/build-system/builder-model/src/main/java/com/android/builder/model/LintOptions.java

Comment: I don't want to disable lint, I just want to hide those 4 lines if the number of issues is 0. That is I want those 2 options I quoted (or something else) to actually have an effect.

Comment: I think you should link to the [documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Lint-support), but it's nice to know where the code lies. Probably I should debug why `textOutput` is not working.

Comment: You are right, sorry! I check the code (and edited the post) but I didn't find how to achieve this.

Comment: I think it'll be set by `lintVitalRelease` if `checkReleaseBuilds true`. and yep, it seems like `println` is the new `System.out.println` you can't get rid of ...